# ¿Cómo pasar un número a string y formatearlo como moneda?

Tags: c#

Trabajo con *Unity* y *C#* y quisiera poder formatear un `string` de texto  para que siga este formato:

- `$ 999.99` y una letra.

Cuando los valores son mayores de `999`. Por ejemplo:

- `123` sería `$ 123`
- `61482` sería `S 61.48 K`
- `4201337` sería `$ 4.20 M`

Es para un juego que estoy haciendo y quiero poder visualizar el dinero de manera más limpia.

Answer (score 15):

Puedes aplicar formato usando

[Cadenas con formato numérico personalizado](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-numeric-format-strings)

[Cadenas con formato numérico estándar](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings)

Si tienes un valor numerico puedes aplicar formato usando

```
int val1 = 123;

string texto1 = val1.ToString("C");
```

al usar `C` aplicas un formato de moneda agregando el signo.

```
int val1 = 61482;

string texto1 = string.Format("S {0:N2} K", val1 / (decimal)1000);
```

aplicas un formato numerico de dos decimales

```
int val1 = 4201337;

string texto1 = string.Format("{0:C2} M", val1 / (decimal)1000000);
```

aplicas un formato de moneda con solo 2 decimales

Answer (score 0):

Con este código se formatean los datos a presentar a la vez que se decide, mediante los if, cual de ellos será el que se muestre en la salida. Por supuesto todo en C#.

Hay tres bloques distintos. El primero muestra el resultado sin decimales y el resultado se redondea. Los otros dos bloques se muestran con dos decimales pero tienen dos estructuras distintas. Las dos son validas.

Personalmente prefiero el ejemplo número 2, por cuestiones prácticas y de estética.

```
//1- Sin decimales redondeado 
double number = 12345.678901; //Ejmeplo ->12 K
string a = "";
string stFormat ="";
if (number >= 0 ) stFormat= "{0:#,0}";
if (number >= 1e3 ) stFormat= "{0:#,0, K}";
if (number >= 1e6 ) stFormat= "{0:#,0,, M}";
if (number >= 1e9 ) stFormat= "{0:#,0,,, G}";
a = string.Format(stFormat,number);
Console.WriteLine(a);

//2- Con dos decimales
number = 123456789.01; //Ejmeplo ->123,46 M
if (number >= 0 ) stFormat= "{0:#,0.00}";
if (number >= 1e3 ) stFormat= "{0:#,0,.00 K}";
if (number >= 1e6 ) stFormat= "{0:#,0,,.00 M}";
if (number >= 1e9 ) stFormat= "{0:#,0,,,.00 G}";
a = string.Format(stFormat,number);
Console.WriteLine(a);

//3- Dos decimales pero menos estetico.
number = 12345.678901; //Ejmeplo ->12,35 K            
if (number >= 1e9 ){
    stFormat= "{0:#,0,,,.00 G}";
}else{
    if (number >= 1e6 ){
        stFormat= "{0:#,0,,.00 M}";
    }else{
        if (number >= 1e3 ){
            stFormat= "{0:#,0,.00 K}";
        }else{
            if (number >= 0 ) stFormat= "{0:#,0.00}";
        }
    }
}
a = string.Format(stFormat,number);
Console.WriteLine(a);
```

Debido a la forma en la que se ha escrito la condición en los *if* es imperativo el orden de todos ellos.